# Cocos2d-x schedule error

Tags: cocos2d-x, schedule

`allyMonser` is a `CCSprite` (Inheritance). When I use schedule, `allyMonster` is `NULL` in `action()`. But, When I call `action()` directly, `allyMonster` is Not `NULL`, it is normal.

When I run this code, the log shows:

```
1, 0x23ds566
2, 0xfffffff
```

I want know the reason `1, 0x23ds566` -> `2, 0xfffffff`. Why does it change?

```
void AMS_Moving::runAction()
{
    allyMonster->unscheduleAllSelectors();
    allyMonster->stopAllActions();
    allyMonster->schedule( schedule_selector( AMS_Moving::action ) );

    CCLog("1. %x", allyMonster);
}

void AMS_Moving::action()
{
    CCLog("2. %x", allyMonster);
    ...
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is, when you run the scheduled function, it is not pointing to the function you want, but something else, because

```
void AMS_Moving::action()
```

is wrong. by default, all schedule function should take an input ccTime dt, which should be

```
void AMS_Moving::action(ccTime dt)
```